# not able to understand the output of a recursion program in python

Tags: python, recursion

```
def add(a):
    a = a + 1
    print(a)
    if a < 10:
        add(a)
    print(a)
add(1)
```

[image: here is the executed code]

I don't understand why the value of `a` started reducing after 10 when it should've stopped at 10 even without an else statement. Can anyone explain the reason?

Comment: Do you understand that `print(1);print("bob");print(1);` prints 1 twice?

Comment: It isn’t reducing… it is showing the value of `a` as it steps out of the recursion. Recursion stops when you reach `a = 10` because of the `if a < 10:`, then your second print runs for the current iteration, then it can run for the previous iteration and so on.

Comment: The short answer is that you `print(a)` twice, so you will see every value of `a` printed twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### print() debugging

```
def add(a):
    a = a + 1
    print(f"#1, a: {a}, id: {id(a)}")
    if a < 10:
        add(a)
    print(f"#2, a: {a}, id: {id(a)}")

add(1)

# stdout:
#1, a: 2, id: 9801280
#1, a: 3, id: 9801312
#1, a: 4, id: 9801344
#1, a: 5, id: 9801376
#1, a: 6, id: 9801408
#1, a: 7, id: 9801440
#1, a: 8, id: 9801472
#1, a: 9, id: 9801504
#1, a: 10, id: 9801536
#2, a: 10, id: 9801536
#2, a: 9, id: 9801504
#2, a: 8, id: 9801472
#2, a: 7, id: 9801440
#2, a: 6, id: 9801408
#2, a: 5, id: 9801376
#2, a: 4, id: 9801344
#2, a: 3, id: 9801312
#2, a: 2, id: 9801280
```

And if you disassemble:

```
import dis
    
dis.dis(add)
```

The bytecode doesn't show any [`BINARY_SUBTRACT`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BINARY_SUBTRACT) operation.

### Explanation

1. The `if` statement recursively executes `add()` until the last line of the function, which then "waits" for the older `add()` calls to end.
2. Each *n* call was called by the  *n-1* one, as it is shown on the stdout: this results in all these waiting stacked calls being executed in a **LIFO** order.
3. At the end, `a`'s value is **not being decremented**, instead is printed with the old values from each previous stacked call, in a "chiastic" fashion.

### Extra

This kind of recursion can be used for printing pyramids (double top) on the stdout:

```
def print_pyramid(a):
    a = a + 1
    print(a*'*')
    if a < 5:
        print_pyramid(a)
    print(a*'*')
    
print_pyramid(0)

# stdout:
*
**
***
****
*****
*****
****
***
**
*
```